# Data gone after changing route

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, google-cloud-firestore

My data is gone after changing route.

Scenario:

CommentComponent (Data shown) -> ChangeRoute -> CommentComponent (No data shown)

The data only shown at the first load, but then it's gone whenever I change the route.

I found this question looks similar with my case/issue:
[No data for FireStore after use of routerlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395598/no-data-for-firestore-after-use-of-routerlink)

But none of the comments/answer is helpful. So I decided to make this question.

COMPONENT.HTML: `comment.component.html`:

```
<ng-template #noComments>
  <h1>No comment yet.</h1>
</ng-template>
<div *ngIf="comments?.length > 0; else noComments">
  <h1 style="margin-bottom: 3.5vh;">Comments</h1>
  <ul *ngFor="let comment of comments">
      <li>
        <mat-card>
          <h3>{{comment.name}}</h3>
          <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
        </mat-card>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

COMPONENT.TypeScript: `comment.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { CommentService } from '../services/comment.service';
import { Comment } from '../models/comment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comment',
  templateUrl: './comment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comment.component.css']
})
export class CommentComponent implements OnInit {

  comments: Comment[];

  constructor(private commentService: CommentService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.commentService.getComments().subscribe(comments => {
      this.comments = comments;
    });
  }

}
```

SERVICE: `comments.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Comment } from '../models/comment';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Injectable()
export class CommentService {

  commentsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Comment>;
  comments: Observable<Comment[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.commentsCollection = this.afs.collection('comments');
    this.comments = this.commentsCollection.valueChanges();
  }

  getComments() {
    return this.comments;
  }

}
```

MODEL: `comments.ts`:

```
export interface Comment {
    name: string;
    comment: string;
}
```

[SOLVED]

Here's how:

In `comment.service.ts`, do something from:

```
  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.commentsCollection = this.afs.collection('comments');
    this.comments = this.commentsCollection.valueChanges();
  }

  getComments() {
    return this.comments;
  }
```

To this:

```
  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
  }

  getComments() {
    this.commentsCollection = this.afs.collection('comments');
    return this.comments = this.commentsCollection.valueChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Sorry not really following what do you mean by data gone when you change route. So if you change route, the component will be destroyed, hence any data set on the component state will be gone. Are you switching to a completely different route or is the comments component still being rendered? Or do you mean going to a different route and then coming back to the comments component?

Comment: @HugoNoro yes, Going to a different route then back again to comment components.

Data was shown before, then I gone to different route and back again to Comment route, the data is gone.

Comment: Thanks, you're my saviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me the issue is you’re initially setting the comments on the service constructor, meaning it will only happen once. Since most likely this is an http call the observable will complete immediately after returning. In the component after changing route and navigating to it again is not restarting the observable só the subscription will never receive any values. The observable has completed already.

I believe that if you move the code you have inside the constructor to the getComments() method it should fix your problem.

Comment: Let me try. Thanks anyway.

Comment: GODDAMNIT YOU FIX MY PROBLEM THANKS!

Comment: Always glad to help :). Most importantly, did you understand why?